# Rust + Tokio: Process First Task to Complete

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

In Tokio, how do you wait for the first task in a list of tasks to complete? The size of the list is unknown.

More specifically:

1. You have a list of tasks.
2. Wait for the first that completes.
3. Run some code, including possibly adding more tasks to the list.
4. Repeat until the list is empty.

The context is that I'm trying to write a function that will run at most N tasks at a time.

Comment: Tokio has a [`block_on`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.block_on) function which suspends execution until a `Future` completes, but there might be a better approach than async if you are only wanting to run one task at a time. A thread pool might be more what you're looking for?

Comment: If you want to wait for the first task to complete, can't you just `.await` it?

Comment: No, process the first task that completes. I believe the answer is unorderedfutures.

Answer (score 2):

If using `tokio`, the general template is this:

```rust
use futures::stream::FuturesUnordered;
use tokio::task::JoinHandle;

let futs = data
    .into_iter()
    .map(|datum| {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            compute_value(datum)
        })
    })
    // The _ is inferred to be the return type of `compute_value`
    .collect::<FuturesUnordered<JoinHandle<_>>>();

while let Some(result) = futs.next().await {
    let value = result?;  // a potential stream error
    // use value
}
```

Comment: Should it be FuturesUnordered if I'm trying to get the first one that completes?

Comment: Yes, the Unordered means exactly that. Ordered would mean that the results would be yielded in the same order as they were submitted (i.e., according to the order of `data`). Unordered means to ignore the order in which they were submitted and yield them as soon as they're ready.

Comment: This may not work with (3)—adding more items to the queue when a process completes. Can you make the answer work with that?

Comment: @Test could you add a more detailed example of what you want? For example, where are this tasks coming from, their type, and adding the code where you want to process them would be very useful too. From what you are saying, you just want to consume a stream.

Comment: To submit a future to an existing collection you can use https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/struct.FuturesUnordered.html#method.push